# no grid layout in firefox dev tools when in shadow root

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

When I have a CSS grid inside a shadow root,
Firefox dev tools doesn't show it in the layout grid pane.
It just says CSS *Grid is not in use on this page*

CSS Grids that are not inside a shadow root do show up correctly.

I did not find any information about it
(aka:

- it's not possible..
- a bug in version x.x.x...
- or whatever...

)

I've tried to create a new profile -> same result...

Screen shot from my dev tools:
[image]

Firefox: 102.0.1 (64-bit) Win10

Answer (score 1):

Answer from
[Inspect Shadow DOM with Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490300/inspect-shadow-dom-with-firefox):

> 1. Type `about:config` in the browser address bar.
> 2. Set `devtools.inspector.showUserAgentShadowRoots` to `true` // not needed for Firefox 76+
> 3. Set `devtools.inspector.showAllAnonymousContent` to `true` (Firefox 76+)

Comment: It is already set to true. I wouldn't see the shadow-dom at all when set to false. The question wasn't about how to inspect the shadow-dom.

Comment: Check other entries containing the string `shadow` in `about:config`. Perhaps something new is required now. Question: When you right-click the shadow element, do you have an Inspect option?

Comment: Yes, I can inspect the grid and all its siblings via the right click menu inside the browser view.

Comment: Dies that include the CSS?

Comment: Yes, I also tried restart in addons disabled mode, I even re-installed firefox (clean install).. nothing changes that Firefox can't see the grid in the layout tab. Flexbox items show up in their Flexbox tab. The grid overlay in the browser view works as well. So I really don't know - but not a great deal - it just annoys me why the heck it doesn't show up...

Comment: Btw. same result with the Firefox developer edition. Perhaps because my grid is inside a web-component which has serveral other nested web-components inside...

Comment: The whole idea of the Shadow DOM with Firefox is that you shouldn't be able to see it. Your case seems just too complicated, with several levels of shadow. You could create a bug report on the Firefox forums.

Comment: Not sure about this; in my opinion the *whole idea* is that outside css doesn't *bleed in*.. why should't I be able to see it? Anyway, thx for taking time to try to help!